# PySpark DataFrames: filter where some value is in array column

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame in PySpark that has a nested array value for one of its fields. I would like to filter the DataFrame where the array contains a certain string. I'm not seeing how I can do that.

The schema looks like this:

    `root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lastName: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)`

I want to return all the rows where the `upper(name) == 'JOHN'` and where the `lastName` column (the array) contains `'SMITH'` and the equality there should be case insensitive (like I did for the name). I found the `isin()` function on a column value, but that seems to work backwards of what I want. It seem like I need a `contains()` function on a column value. Anyone have any ideas for a straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An update in 2019

spark 2.4.0 introduced new functions like `array_contains` and `transform`
[official document](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#array_contains)
now it can be done in sql language

For your problem, it should be

```
dataframe.filter('array_contains(transform(lastName, x -> upper(x)), "JOHN")')
```

It is better than the previous solution using `RDD` as a bridge, because `DataFrame` operations are much faster than `RDD` ones.

Answer (score 3):

You could consider working on the underlying RDD directly.

```
def my_filter(row):
    if row.name.upper() == 'JOHN':
        for it in row.lastName:
            if it.upper() == 'SMITH':
                yield row

dataframe = dataframe.rdd.flatMap(my_filter).toDF()
```