# Filter PySpark DataFrame by checking if string appears in column

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to Spark and playing around with filtering. I have a pyspark.sql DataFrame created by reading in a json file. A part of the schema is shown below:

```
root
 |-- authors: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

I would like to filter this DataFrame, selecting all of the rows with entries pertaining to a particular author. So whether this author is the first author listed in `authors` or the nth, the row should be included if their name appears. So something along the lines of

```
df.filter(df['authors'].getItem(i)=='Some Author')
```

where `i` iterates through all authors in that row, which is not constant across rows.

I tried implementing the solution given to [PySpark DataFrames: filter where some value is in array column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38019921/pyspark-dataframes-filter-where-some-value-is-in-array-column), but it gives me

> **ValueError:** Some of types cannot be determined by the first 100 rows,
>   please try again with sampling

Is there a succinct way to implement this filter?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `pyspark.sql.functions.array_contains` method:

```
df.filter(array_contains(df['authors'], 'Some Author'))
```

---

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import array_contains

lst = [(["author 1", "author 2"],), (["author 2"],) , (["author 1"],)]
schema = StructType([StructField("authors", ArrayType(StringType()), True)])
df = spark.createDataFrame(lst, schema)
df.show()
+--------------------+
|             authors|
+--------------------+
|[author 1, author 2]|
|          [author 2]|
|          [author 1]|
+--------------------+

df.printSchema()
root
 |-- authors: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

df.filter(array_contains(df.authors, "author 1")).show()
+--------------------+
|             authors|
+--------------------+
|[author 1, author 2]|
|          [author 1]|
+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 3):

Just complementing the nice answer from @Psidom.
I know that your column `author` is an array, but for another type of column (like string), you could do this:

```
df.filter(df.authors.contains('Some Author')).show()
```